# Explaining the scoping of variables in recursive functions

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to explain to a student I am helping out at school with an ICT exam question on Javascript how the function below is returning 24. I am an economics teacher by training who dabbles in programming. I know it is a simple example of recursion but I am not sure of the actual step by step process and the scoping of the variable N. Is anyone able to explain step by step and clearly how this is working.

```
function mystery(n){
 if(n==0)
 return 1;
 return  n* mystery(n-1);
}

console.log(mystery(4));
```

Comment: Why not simply write the steps on a piece of paper? `mystery(4)` -> `4 * mystery(3)` -> `3 * mystery(2)` -> `2 * mystery(1)` -> `1 * mystery(0)` -> `1` => `1 * 2 * 3 * 4` (`n` is just a local variable)

Comment: Not related to your question, but as a matter of style, if you really must omit the `{...}` from a single-statement `if` body, then please put it on the same line as the `if`. It's much too liable to cause confusion otherwise (it's not instantly apparent that the second `return` isn't inside the `if` statemenet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enhance the function with a bit of logging it's easy to visualize the recursion depth and the way it descends and ascends into each call:

```
function log(indentation) {
  var args = ['  '.repeat(indentation)]
    .concat(Array.from(arguments).slice(1));
  console.log.apply(null, args);
}

function mystery(n, depth) {
  if (n === 0) {
    log(depth, 'mystery called with n =', n, 'returning 1');
    return 1;
  } else {
    log(
      depth, 'mystery called with n =', n,
     'going into recursion: multiplying with mystery(', n - 1, ')'
    );
    var result = n * mystery(n - 1, depth + 1);
    log(
      depth, 'mystery called with n =', n,
      'returning', result, ' after recursion'
    );
    return result;
  }
}

var initialDepth = 0;
mystery(4, initialDepth);


// Output:

mystery called with n = 4 going into recursion: multiplying with mystery( 3 )
  mystery called with n = 3 going into recursion: multiplying with mystery( 2 )
    mystery called with n = 2 going into recursion: multiplying with mystery( 1 )
      mystery called with n = 1 going into recursion: multiplying with mystery( 0 )
        mystery called with n = 0 returning 1
      mystery called with n = 1 returning 1  after recursion
    mystery called with n = 2 returning 2  after recursion
  mystery called with n = 3 returning 6  after recursion
mystery called with n = 4 returning 24  after recursion
```

Answer (score 1):

Step by step

```js
function mystery(n){
 console.log('n=',n); // I add this to see 'call stack'
 if(n==0) return 1;
 return n * mystery(n-1);
}

console.log(mystery(4));

// Execution looks like this
//
// 1. console.log(mystery(4));
// 2. run for n=4
//  function mystery(4){
//   if(4==0) return 1;
//   return 4 * mystery(4-1);  // we call here mystery(3)
//  }
// 3. The mystery(3) is
//  function mystery(3){
//   if(3==0) return 1;
//   return 3 * mystery(3-1);  // we call here mystery(2)
//  }
// 4. The mystery(2) is
//  function mystery(2){
//   if(2==0) return 1;
//   return 2 * mystery(2-1);  // we call here mystery(1)
//  }
// 5. The mystery(1) is
//  function mystery(1){
//   if(1==0) return 1;
//   return 1 * mystery(1-1);  // we call here mystery(0)
//  }
// 6. The mystery(0) is
//  function mystery(0){
//   if(0==0) return 1;  // we return 1 here
//   return 0 * mystery(0-1);  
//  }
//
// So at the end the  mystery(4) returns:
// return 4 * 3 * 2 *1 * 1
```